# Python : Is a number too big?

Tags: python, integer

I've learnt that python supports very large numbers with `int` itself.

But in this case :

```
 print(int(12630717197566440579/10))
```

My answer is

```
1263071719756644096
```

and not

```
1263071719756644057
```

As it's supposed to be.

Can someone tell me why?

Comment: The first calculation is floating point math. Now have a look at [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/588014/3929826)! And compare with `12630717197566440579//10`.

Comment: Using regular division creates a limited precision float which you subsequently turn into an int. The conversion to an int doesn't undo the loss of precision. Just use integer division. //